# Why does the link appear before the table when it's after it in the HTML?

Tags: html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Firecore's Profile</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color:#DC143C; text-align:center">
            <p><h1>Firecore Starblade</h1></p>
        </div>
            <p style="text-align:center">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRz83KYRPqRKFLb4rtJdS6JzGL-OZ-OhSVE5nOz1Q7CZ3seOe1-"; width="10%" ; height="10%">
        </p>
        <div>
            <table border="1px" align="center">
                <thead style="background-color:#DC143C">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Attributes</th>
                        <th>HP</th>
                        <th>AP</th>
                        <th>Dex</th>
                        <th>Str</th>
                        <th>Int</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color:#DC143C"><strong>Value</strong></td>
                        <td>100</td>
                        <td>50</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                        <td>10</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <a href="firecoreMain.html">Back</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just starting out learning HTML. Making a practice site and ran into this problem. Tried googling it but unable to locate the cause. Not understanding why the "Back" HyperLink is showing above the table instead of below. I thought maybe it was because of the uses of p and div elements but i tried different combos with no luck. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You have a missing `>` on the closing `</tbody` tag

Comment: The solution is indeed the missing `>`. I'd be interested if someone can work out *why*, though...

Comment: Also there is no need to have semicolons after each attribute on your `img` tag

Comment: duh ... the simple things ...thanks so much

Comment: Ok thanks for all the help, cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a simple problem, but it's actually really interesting. On a simple level, the problem is that the `</tbody>` tag is missing the closing `>`. Put it in and your code works.

But the more interesting question is **why?**

Well, it turns out that the problem is that you are in fact not closing the `table` tag. Your missing `>` essentially means you have a tag that looks like this: `</tbody </table>`. That's one tag and the browser will think "ah, we're closing the `tbody` and we've got some other stuff that doesn't make sense here so we're going to ignore it."

So you never actually close the `table` tag. This means that you now have some invalid markup in your table. To be precise, the following code is now part of your table's code:

```
        </div>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <a href="firecoreMain.html">Back</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is handled according to the rather obscure rules listed here in [the HTML5 specification section "Unexpected markup in tables"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#unexpected-markup-in-tables). The basic meaning of all that specification (which the W3C confesses is "for historical reasons, especially strange") is that all the unexpected/invalid markup inside the table gets put before the beginning of the table.

That's why your link does the surprising thing of moving before the table. A simple mistake (the missing `>`) has ended up sending your browser down a whole rabbit warren of mistaken parsing.

Comment: [validators](https://validator.nu) are your friend when faced with unexpected behavior like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have a broken close tag for tbody.

```html
<div style="background-color:#DC143C; text-align:center">
  <p>
    <h1>Firecore Starblade</h1>
  </p>
</div>
<p style="text-align:center">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRz83KYRPqRKFLb4rtJdS6JzGL-OZ-OhSVE5nOz1Q7CZ3seOe1-" ; width="10%" ; height="10%">
</p>
<div>
  <table border="1px" align="center">
    <thead style="background-color:#DC143C">
      <tr>
        <th>Attributes</th>
        <th>HP</th>
        <th>AP</th>
        <th>Dex</th>
        <th>Str</th>
        <th>Int</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#DC143C"><strong>Value</strong>
        </td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <a href="firecoreMain.html">Back</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Close your

https://jsfiddle.net/Delorian/pygbjfk6/

```
</tbody>
```

P.S. using JS Fiddle or a similar tool is a good way to learn HTML & CSS, as is getting to grips with Developer Tool in Chrome for manipulating HTML, CSS & JS on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

As another note, any text *inside* the **table** but *outside* the **table elements** (between cells or rows) will also be collected immediately before the table(separated by spaces if you have multiple instances of this) when it is rendered.
This is important to know so if you see wierd text showing up just above your table, you most likely have stray text being generated either in the wrong place, or completly erroneosly.